# Ng-model in directive dont change parent scope in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a html template with directive and patricular scope variable (mySelections_class_list):

```
<pre>{{mySelections_class_list|json}}</pre>
<ng-data-grid cells="columnDefsClassList" rows="class_list" my-selections="mySelections_class_list" lang="lang"></ng-data-grid>
```

I have a directive, this is code of directive:

```
    directives.directive('ngDataGrid', ['$rootScope','$location', '$hotkey','$timeout', function($rootScope, $location, $hotkey,$timeout){
            return {
                transclude: true,
                restrict: "EAC",
                templateUrl: 'templates/panels/ng-data-grid.html',
                scope: {
                    cells: "=",
                    rows: "=",
                    item: "=",
                    mySelections: "=",
                    lang: '='
                },
                controller: ['$scope','$element', function($scope,$element){
                    $scope.mySelections = 'blabla';
                }]
            }
        }]);
```

And directive template, where I have ng-model:

```
     <table kb-list ng-model="mySelections" class="data-grid">
....
        </table>
```

But when I had changed in directive mySelections_class_list, in my parent controller it doesnt change! But in template I saw changes!

So... In template work... but in parent controller :  console.debug($scope.mySelections_class_list) nothing changes! Why!?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the variables of the parent scope inside some object:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.columnDefsClassList = <someValue>;
$scope.model.class_list = <someValue>;
$scope.model.mySelections_class_list = <someValue>;
$scope.model.lang = <someValue>;

<ng-data-grid cells="model.columnDefsClassList" rows="model.class_list" my-selections="model.mySelections_class_list" lang="model.lang"></ng-data-grid>
```

see explanation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

I have been fiddling around a bit and am not sure where your particular issue is coming from in a stripped down jsfiddle and angular 1.3-rc5

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
```

and defined MyCtrl as empty function, it is working as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7769/

Furthermore you should be using your own namespace, ng reserved for angular directives.

hope that helps :)